# Enable double tap event while allowing scrolling using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch-event

I have been developing mobile apps using Cordova/Phonegap and this time I had to enable a double tap on rows of one specific table. I don't want to use a plugin or another library for it as it is only for one part of the app. **How do I check double tap on Javascript?**

Comment: I usually use a library called [quojs](http://quojs.tapquo.com/), recommended 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I searched "How do I check for double tap in javascript?", and voila! using @mfirdaus answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058241/touch-device-single-and-double-tap-events-handler-jquery-javascript) I solved it. But I came to another issue, I cant scroll. So I searched "How do I enable scrolling while checking for double tap?" and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127118/can-you-detect-dragging-in-jquery) very useful.

I compiled both answers to create a function that attaches a double tap event on a given element:

```
var tapped = false;
var isDragging = false;

function attachDoubleTap(elem, callbacks) {
    callbacks = callbacks || {};
    callbacks.onSingleTap = callbacks.onSingleTap || function() {}
    callbacks.onDoubleTap = callbacks.onDoubleTap || function() {}

    $(document)
    .on('touchstart', elem, function(e) {

        $(window).bind('touchmove', function() {
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).unbind('touchmove');
        });
    })
    .on('touchend', elem, function(e) {

        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        $(window).unbind("touchmove");
        if (!wasDragging) { //was clicking

            //detect single or double tap
            var _this = $(this);
            if(!tapped){ //if tap is not set, set up single tap
              tapped=setTimeout(function(){
                  tapped=null
                  //insert things you want to do when single tapped
                  callbacks.onSingleTap(_this);

              },200);   //wait 300ms then run single click code
            } else {    //tapped within 300ms of last tap. double tap
              clearTimeout(tapped); //stop single tap callback
              tapped=null

              //insert things you want to do when double tapped
              callbacks.onDoubleTap(_this);

            }
        }
    })
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  attachDoubleTap('#canvas', {
    onSingleTap: function() {
      $('.msg').text('single tap');
    },
    onDoubleTap: function() {
      $('.msg').text('double tap');
    },
    onMove: function() {
      $('.msg').text('moved');
    }
  });
});




var tapped = false;
var isDragging = false;

function attachDoubleTap(elem, callbacks) {
  callbacks = callbacks || {};
  callbacks.onSingleTap = callbacks.onSingleTap || function() {}
  callbacks.onDoubleTap = callbacks.onDoubleTap || function() {}
  callbacks.onMove = callbacks.onMove || function() {}

  $(document)
    .on('touchstart', elem, function(e) {

      $(window).bind('touchmove', function() {
        isDragging = true;
        callbacks.onMove();
        $(window).unbind('touchmove');
      });
    })
    .on('touchend', elem, function(e) {

      var wasDragging = isDragging;
      isDragging = false;
      $(window).unbind("touchmove");
      if (!wasDragging) { //was clicking

        //detect single or double tap
        var _this = $(this);
        if (!tapped) { //if tap is not set, set up single tap
          tapped = setTimeout(function() {
            tapped = null
              //insert things you want to do when single tapped
            callbacks.onSingleTap(_this);

          }, 200); //wait 300ms then run single click code
        } else { //tapped within 300ms of last tap. double tap
          clearTimeout(tapped); //stop single tap callback
          tapped = null

          //insert things you want to do when double tapped
          callbacks.onDoubleTap(_this);

        }
      }
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #b0dddf;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.msg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="canvas">
  <ul>
    <li>Try to tap once</li>
    <li>Try to tap twice</li>
    <li>Try to tap and drag</li>
  </ul>

  <div class='msg'></div>

</div>
```

**I hope this helps someone in the future.** (*I only included the Move() callback on the snippet to show it is working, it is up to you to add it to the function*)