# Activate javascript touchmove on mobile devices only when with two fingers

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have a animated area which i activated for mobile devices via javascript touchmove event but on horizontal mobile screens there is an issue of scrolling down over the animated touch area. Here is my code

```
jQuery(".animatedPhone").bind('touchmove', function(jQueryEvent) {});
```

Is there a way how i can activate the touchmove only when user uses his two fingers like google map is doing when on mobile?

I tried the below code

```
$(".animatedPhone").on("touchstart",function(e){
    if(!tapped){ //if tap is not set, set up single tap
        tapped = setTimeout(function(){
          tapped = null;
          //insert things you want to do when single tapped
        },300);   //wait 300ms then run single click code
    } else {    //tapped within 300ms of last tap. double tap
        clearTimeout(tapped); //stop single tap callback
        tapped = null;
        alert('double tapped');
    }
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

But like this again the animated touch area is not scrollable.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't make it an answer, since I do not have a device to test it... But I just found [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) which I think would be usefull to you. -- The trick would be to check the `touches.length` in a function called by the `touchstart` event. I guess you could be safe to disable the scroll if you have two or more.  Or bind the `touchmove` event to your function... Or whatever.

Comment: I checked and is not really working @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Can you detect the amount of fingers on touchstart?

Comment: Tried if (e.touches.length > 1){ // means 2 fingers but it do not do anything

Comment: Try `if (e.changedTouches.length > 1){` ;)

Comment: No does not make sense. Page is being zoomed in

Comment: Just an idea to help... If you disable the scroll on an event like on double-tap (it doesn't exist but you can detect it - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058241/touch-device-single-and-double-tap-events-handler-jquery-javascript)) Maybe?

Comment: I was checking this article just now and result is same. When i have this code added i still cant scroll down over the animated touch area

Comment: You should edit your question with the HTML and relevant script for the touch area. Because what you do now, is asking about a solution you tried instead of asking about your problem. That is called an ["X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). ;) Hopefully, more poeple will be able to help you.